# Predict using individual trees - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

I trained an ensemble model using **fitensemble** with bagging in MATLAB. I want to predict responses for each individual classification tree. I used the function **predict** but it uses all the trees for prediction. I have looked it up all over but couldn't find what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the Examples section on the [help page for ClassificationEnsemble](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationensemble-class.html), if you train an ensemble model `Mdl`:

```
Mdl = fitcensemble(X,Y,'Method','AdaBoostM1')
```

then

> `Mdl.Trained` is the property that stores a 100-by-1 cell vector of the
>   trained classification trees (`CompactClassificationTree` model objects)
>   that compose the ensemble.

so you can access the individual classification models as `Mdl.Trained{1}`, `Mdl.Trained{2}` and so on, and each of them is a `CompactClassificationTree` object with its own `predict` method.

Comment: I have done that but I keep getting the 'Table variable Region is not a valid predictor'  error where _Region_ is one of the predictors used to train the model. When I checked the error further more, I found that it spits out that error when the predictor is not numeric or logical. But isn't it the same case for the entire model?

Comment: Can you edit the question with some example code and the error(s) it produces? If you can't share any of your actual data, can you reproduce the problem using a standard dataset ([sample datasets included with MATLAB](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/sample-data-sets.html))?